# UsedLicenses / TotalLicenses fields are not available

Tags: userlicense

I am trying to fetch UsedLicenses / TotalLicenses from UserLicense object and I am using API 32.0 but when I try to access those fields, error says "No such column 'UsedLicenses' on entity 'UserLicense'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names." 
Also by using developer console I am not able to do that. please suggest.

Comment: Documentation such as [UserLicense](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_userlicense.htm) says "This field is available through the API Access to User Licenses pilot program. For information on enabling this pilot program for your organization, contact Salesforce.". So perhaps a support request is needed to enable the feature.

Comment: Okay then I have to enable that pilot program

Comment: Will this pilot program will be covered in Spring '15 Release?

Answer (score 0):

Vote for [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cJTEAA2) to make it Generally Available.

Also you might be interested in [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dqh3AAC).